# About mysql cursor and iterator

Tags: python, mysql, database-cursor, fetchall

Imagine I have a mysql cursor and data read. The amount of data might be very big that I want to deal with one line each time.

An easy and straight forward way might be like this:

```
while True:
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if not row: break
    .....
```

But this doesn't look good, so I wonder whether this way works as imagined:

```
for row in iter(cursor.fetchall())
```

The thing I want to know is: if I use the `iter(cursor.fetchall())` way, does it fetch all the data first or it just fetch one row at a time?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The `MySQLdb` cursor class implements the [iterator protocol](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__iter__#object.__iter__), so you can simply do this:

```
cursor.execute(sql)
for row in cursor:
    print row
    ...
```

Relevant code from [MySQLdb.cursors.BaseCursor](http://mysql-python.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mysql-python/branches/MySQLdb-1.2/MySQLdb/MySQLdb/cursors.py?revision=629&view=markup):

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.fetchone, None)
```

Comment: Anyway I can get the column names in the for loop?