# Reading from mysql in batch end up hitting all rows

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I am trying to read a 100GB+ table in python using pymysql python package.
the query I am firing is

> select * from table

But I want to be able to process records in chunks instead of hitting the database for 100 GB records, below is my code

```
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
        logging.info("Executing Read query")
        logging.info(cursor.mogrify(query))
        cursor.execute(query)
        schema = cursor.description
        size = cursor.rowcount
        for i in range((size//batch)+1):
            records = cursor.fetchmany(size=batch)
            yield records, schema
```

but when the query gets executed at `cursor.execute(query)` it tried to get those 100GB records and end up killing the process.

Is there any better way to read data in chunk from mysql using python?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195988/about-mysql-cursor-and-iterator

Comment: Any reason you can't paginate through the data using MySQL's [`LIMIT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html#idm139812212181472) functionality?

Comment: What I want to understand is how fetchmany executes, does it asks the mysql for these many of row or results are already there and its just does slicing?