# python cursor to list with condition over entry

Tags: python

I have a cursor object in python. I wish to scrape that to a list.

```
names = []
address = []

for x in curs:
    names.append(x["name"])
    
    if (x["country"]=='USA'):
        address.append(x["country"]+x["pincode"])
    else:
        address.append(x["country"])
```

this is the way I am iterating. Basically add pincode with country IFF country == USA. Else only country. Above piece works But, I wish to know same can be achieved in better/faster way. Right now it is comparing for in entry in curs the country.

Answer (score 2):

I can only give a more pythonic style, but sorry to help little on efficiency.

suppose your `curs` data is somehow like this:

```py
curs = [{"name": "A", "country": "USA", "pincode": "1234"},
        {"name": "B", "country": "UK", "pincode": "5678"}, ]
```

then we can use:

```py
names = [x["name"] for x in curs]
address = [x["country"] + x["pincode"] if (x["country"] == 'USA') else x["country"] for x in curs]
```

to get the same output:

```py
['A', 'B']
['USA1234', 'UK']
```

Comment: Each call on `cursor` with a for loop will fetch every item from the DB. I'm not 100% sure if this works (if you can fetch twice) and even if it did, it takes twice as much time as using the original solution.

Comment: thanks, but it's another problem, in which one should add a line <`d = curs.fetchall()`> at top to fetch data only once, and use `d` as the iterable in the following.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read in [MySQL cursor docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor.html) and [this post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195988/about-mysql-cursor-and-iterator), the code snippet below should work fine.

```py
def decider(val):
    if( val['country'] == 'USA'):
        return val["country"]+ val["pincode"]

    else return
        val["country"]

data = curs.fetchall()
names , adress = map(lambda x: x["names"] , data ) , map(decider , data )
```

However, since `cursor.__iter__()` will fetch items one by one from the DB, performance vise I don't think that there is a difference between using a for loop and a map.
If you want to improve your code performance, you have to use async programming. It goes something like this:
*Fetch the first row from the DB. Begin fetching the second row. While waiting, perform any action you want on the first row until the second row is fetched.*